# Why union of two or more queryset doesn't work perfectly with forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField?

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-queryset

**Hello Awesome People!**

I struggled with this for hours. I have a Form that has a field called `programs`

```
programs = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(queryset=Program.objects.none(),
    required=False, widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple())
```

I did not fill in the query set argument directly because I have a few things to do with it in the views like combining the default `programs` with `programs` chosen by the user.

```
form = CourseForm(request.POST or None)
default_programs = Program.objects.filter(default=True)
all_programs = default_programs.union(user.programs.filter(default=False))
```

So far so good, the queryset works also with the `union`. I assign the queryset to the form field `programs`

```
form.fields['programs'].queryset = all_programs
if request.method == "POST":
    if form.is_valid():
        programs = form.cleaned_data.get("programs")
        ''' stuff '''
        course.programs.add(*programs)
```

The funny thing here is that even though I do not select any items, `programs` always received all the queryset, I tried `course.programs.clear()` before, but it did not work, it's still been assigned by all the programs containing in the `queryset` argument

**Round 2: after 1 hour**

I changed the `union` to `|`, and it works

```
all_programs = (default_programs | user.programs.filter(default=False)).distinct()
```

Does anyone know why it did not work with `union()`, I do not like doing things I do not understand.
`union()` were supposed to work since it's just a combination of 2 queryset of the same model.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They do two different things. I don't think you really wanted a union. You don't want the same result twice if it shows up in both sets. What you want is an or query which is what the bitwise operator gives you. It takes both filters and makes them as if you wrote them as

`Program.objects.filter(Q(default=True) | Q(id__in=user.programs.values('id')))`

Comment: Some would say the way you had it looks better. Either way the point is you want to combine the filters not the results.